# import sql file in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to import a sql file through php via `shell_exec function`. My code is as follows,

```
 shell_exec("C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin>mysql -h localhost -u
 root blank_db < C:\wamp\www\my_web\sql\blank_db.sql")
```

My `database name = "blank_db"`. and there is no password set for mysql.

The above command is running successfully in `cmd`, but not it in php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072479/php-script-to-import-file-in-mysql Here you can find your answer.

Comment: Could you post your PHP script used to import SQL file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the answer of 'Brad F Jacobs' for another  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309094/can-i-automatically-locate-the-mysql-executable-from-php?rq=1) in stack

after steps in this answer, I changed my code as
shell_exec("mysql -h localhost -u
 root blank_db < C:\wamp\www\my_web\sql\blank_db.sql")
then I restarted my computer (or WAMP). all working fine.